# ggplot2 -r- scale_x_discrete to display text

Tags: r

I am trying to display a limited number of observations in the text of the x axis, but maintaining the entire population of discrete observations in the plot:

```
zed <- structure(list(FTD = c(93L, 50L, 88L), FTD_DATE = structure(c(12L, 15L, 2L), .Label = c("01/03/2018", "03/06/2017", "05/05/2017", "08/01/2018", "08/12/2017", "09/07/2017", "11/10/2017", "13/02/2018", "14/09/2017", "15/11/2017", "16/05/2017", "17/11/2017", "18/09/2017", "18/12/2017", "21/07/2017", "21/10/2017", "23/06/2017", "26/05/2017"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("FTD", "FTD_DATE"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=zed, aes(x=FTD_DATE,y=FTD)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text
        (angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1.0)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=FTD_DATE,y=FTD)) +
  scale_x_discrete (breaks=c("05/05/2017","03/06/2017","09/07/2017",
                             "11/10/2017","08/12/2017","08/01/2018",
                             "01/03/2018"))
```

[image]

The above gives me a concentration of text in the left of the x axis (7 dates as per breaks argument in the scale_x_discrete, out of 19 dates in total) but leaving a wide blank space in the remaining portion of the axis... Is there a way to spread evenly the text across the entire x axis, choosing the number of observation I want to display in the text, maintaining the entire number of observation in the plot and ordering the dates in the x axis text in ascending order? Bearing in mind that scale_x_date returns error "Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only".. Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Your question would have a higher chance of being answered.

Comment: Apologies if my question was too generic, Hope this can help? dput(head(zed,3))*** structure(list(FTD = c(93L, 50L, 88L), FTD_DATE = structure(c(12L, 15L, 2L), .Label = c("01/03/2018", "03/06/2017", "05/05/2017", "08/01/2018", "08/12/2017", "09/07/2017", "11/10/2017", "13/02/2018", "14/09/2017", "15/11/2017", "16/05/2017", "17/11/2017", "18/09/2017", "18/12/2017", "21/07/2017", "21/10/2017", "23/06/2017", "26/05/2017"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("FTD", "FTD_DATE"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")***zed is my dataset:  head(zed,1)....  
   FTD   FTD_DATE
1  93 17/11/2017

Comment: You need make sure the minimal example captures the problem. I just updated the question with your dataset, but I don't think it is capturing the error you are explaining? Please use the way I have structured the code as a template if you need to update the question

Comment: Hi Mikey thanks for your input, the graph above actually reproduces the issue: as you can see there are 3 dots in the scatterplot and one vertical axis text only (03/06/2017). The entire dataset (zed) is made of 19 dots (19 observations) and I wish to keep them all in the scatterplot but showing only 6 or 7 x axis texts in the x axis. My goal is to spread the text in the x axis evenly from left to right and to order the FTD_DATE dates in ascending order (which is to say the first and the last texts must be placed at the extreme left and right of the x axis, showing min and max values)..

Answer (score 0):

Your dates are currently text in dd/mm/yyyy form which cannot be ordered correctly as they stand. You can convert the FTD_DATE column to a true date format, then use the scale_x_date method of ggplot2 to set whatever period is appropriate for the range of dates you are displaying.

**Test Data**

I've expanded your test data from three points to 18, keeping the labels you had in your struct but with some dummy FTD values:

```
zed <- data.frame(FTD = rep(c(93L, 50L, 88L, 66L, 75L, 94L), 3), 
                  FTD_DATE = c("01/03/2018", "03/06/2017", "05/05/2017", "08/01/2018", "08/12/2017", "09/07/2017", "11/10/2017", "13/02/2018", "14/09/2017", "15/11/2017", "16/05/2017", "17/11/2017", "18/09/2017", "18/12/2017", "21/07/2017", "21/10/2017", "23/06/2017", "26/05/2017"))
```

**Conversion to date**

```
zed$FTD_DATE = as.Date(zed$FTD_DATE, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

**ggplot - breaks set to two weeks**

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=zed, aes(x=FTD_DATE,y=FTD)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text
        (angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1.0)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=FTD_DATE,y=FTD)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 weeks")
```

[image]

**Breaks set to month**

```
ggplot(data=zed, aes(x=FTD_DATE,y=FTD)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text
        (angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1.0)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=FTD_DATE,y=FTD)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "month")
```

[image]

As you see, the points are plotted in ordered form left to right as you want, and the choice of date_breaks controls the number of labels shown on each plot.

Comment: Wonderful solution, your answer is exactly what I was trying to solve. I upvoted your answer. Thanks Stewart

Comment: Glad to have helped!